# Observer will not fire after upgrade to 1.0

Tags: ember.js

THis code used to work prior to upgrading to 1.0

```
Radium.AuthManager = Ember.Object.extend
  _token: null
  init: ->
    @_super.apply this, arguments
    @set('token', $.cookie('token'))

  token: ((key, value) ->
    if arguments.length == 2
      @set '_token', value
      return

    @get('_token')
  ).property('_token').volatile()

  setAjaxHeaders: ( ->
    if token = @get('_token')
      $.ajaxSetup
        headers:
          "X-User-Token": token
  ).observes('_token')

  tokenDidChange: ( ->
    token = @get('_token')

    return unless Ember.isEmpty(token)

    location.replace('http://blah')
  ).observes('token')
```

After upgrade to 1.0 it no longer works.

Can observers really be broken or has it changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previous behavior was that a `set()` call in `init()` will trigger observer; the current behavior is that it won't.

Before:

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    this.set('salutation', "Mr/Ms");
  },

  salutationDidChange: function() {
    // fired
  }.observes('salutation')
});
```

Now:

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function() {
    this.set('salutation', "Mr/Ms");
  },

  salutationDidChange: function() {
    // fired
  }.observes('salutation').on('init')
});
```

Example taken directly from the [release notes](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/08/29/ember-1-0-rc8.html).

Just add those `on('init')` tags to your observers:

```
Radium.AuthManager = Ember.Object.extend
  # ...
  setAjaxHeaders: ( ->
    # ...
  ).observes('_token').on('init')

  tokenDidChange: ( ->
    # ...
  ).observes('token').on('init')
```